# Criar um pacote que depende de outros pacotes

Tags: r, packages

Pessoal estou criando um pacote com algumas funções uma delas depende de outro pacote, como "dá o sinal" para o R entender e instalar esse pacote? O pacote que dependo é o `raster`.

```
a = matrix(c(0,0,2,0,2,2,0,2), byrow = T, ncol = 2)
b = list(matrix(c(0.5, 0 ,1 , 1, 1.5, 0), ncol = 2, byrow = T))

polygon.intersection <- function(polygon1,polygon2){
  polygon11 = as(polygon1, "gpc.poly")
  polygon22 = as(polygon2, "gpc.poly")
  res = intersect(polygon11, polygon22)
  if(is.na(get.bbox(res)$x[[1]])) res = matrix(c(0,0,0,0), ncol = 2)

  else res1 = as(res, "matrix")
  res1
}
polygon.intersection(a,b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No diretório em que está o código do seu pacote, deve existir um arquivo de metadados chamado `DESCRIPTION`. Neste arquivo, um dos campos que pode ser incluído é o `Imports`, que indica que seu pacote depende de outro(s) pacote(s) para funcionar.

Por exemplo, seu arquivo poderia conter o seguinte:

```
Imports:
    raster,
    sp
```

Veja que o seu pacote não instala por si só os outros pacotes, mas estas dependências são lidas quando alguém rodar `install.packages()` e todos os pacotes importados também são instalados.

Recomendo a leitura do [site do Hadley](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/description.html) para mais detalhes sobre a criação de pacotes.

Comment: O meu `import` tá assim, mas não está funcionando.

Comment: Por que não funciona? O `Imports` não carrega o pacote, só muda a instalação. O ideal é você sempre usar `pacote::função` pra não ter que usar `library` e deixar o código mais claro.